# how to put modules in path after installing them via NPM

Tags: npm, webpack

I installed webpack and webpack-dev-server using NPM.

```
npm i webpack webpack-dev-server --save
```

I also did

```
npm link webpack webpack-dev-server
```

Now when I type webpack in the root of my project it says

```
'webpack' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

I would hate it that everytime i install something I have to manually edit the path variable of my OS.

is there a better way of putting these utilities so that I can invoke them ... without editing my OS path variable?

Answer (score 2):

> is there a better way of putting these utilities so that I can invoke them ... without editing my OS path variable?

Yes, there is, `npm i webpack -g`

Comment: I don't like installing modules globally. I work on different projects which can use different versions of modules.

Comment: What's the difference between install globally and edit OS path?
I think theses module we need install globally most time are dev dependencies.